# Share Laravel project in different PC git project

Tags: laravel

I made a project in laravel and upload in git to share to my friends but while he pull the project and run it it show the sql

PDOException (1045)

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Because he hasn't got a root user without a password on his database on localhost. Or he has no root user in his database on localhost. Or he has no database on localhost.

Comment: I gave him the sql file and imort into the MySQL database.
his user is root and has password!

Comment: Then something is wrong in your code because the error states `using password: NO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ask your friend to fix app/config/database.php mysql block, it should look like

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'databasename',
            'username'  => 'username',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

also edit your .gitignore file in the root directory of your project and add the following line

```
app/config/database.php
```

if you don't have .gitignore file run touch .gitignore this file takes care of what not to upload on git ask your friend to do the same

Answer (score 0):

If he is using Laravel Homestead he should change the database credentials to the ones in his database.